# Charts with vertical separation in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

[image]

I need to design a chart as displayed above. Its like, one x- axis and multiple Left y - axis.

When i keep my cursor anywhere in any one of the 3, all should be updated with the positioned value in the legendary section.

I am checking for options to implement in Jquery.

If not jquery, should end up with any other feature or plug-in to implement this requirement.

Please advise!

Prag